# Webpack 4 bundle throws error __webpack_require__ is not defined in browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting this error in browser **__webpack_require__ is not defined**  after bundling
Using the latest version of WebPack 4
Configuration link: https://gist.github.com/prad9/6daec7b3a1c49a2536ef26239e484c65

Any help would be appreciated